# Oracle SELECT UNIQUE * FROM TABLE

Tags: sql, oracle

It is acceptable in Oracle databases the command

```
  "SELECT UNIQUE * FROM table"?
```

Or do I have to select the column name for that command to work?

Comment: Distinct........... ?

Comment: Why have you got duplicated rows in your table? Needing this would concern me, a lot...

Comment: It shouldn't right since I suppose to have only one id right?

Comment: If I put that query I shouldn't return any row since I suppose to have a primary key which is unique right? I can't text the query right now...

Comment: `DISTINCT` and `UNIQUE` are [Synonymous](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF55166). And yes it fetches distinct of rows across all the columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this syntax is acceptable. 
See this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce01b/2).

Answer (score 2):

you can use the following query

```
select distinct * from table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use UNIQUE (or DISTINCT) if your table has LOB fields.
See example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97d3e/1